# Set different language on assistant using hotword sample script

Tags: raspberry-pi3, google-assistant-sdk

I am running the Google Assistant SDK on a Raspberry PI 3.

With the recent [update](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-assistant-sdk-updates/zMVgRYQpgpw) to the Google Assistant SDK, it is mentioned that we should now be able to change the language of the assistant running on our device.

After registering the model and creating an instance of the device ([as per the instructions](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/library/python/)), I can now see the device under the "My Devices" section of the Google Assistant App. I set the language to French but still the assistant is listening and speaking in English.

After looking at the [sample code](https://github.com/googlesamples/assistant-sdk-python) on Github, I see that there is a `--lang` flag that can be used for the textinput.py and pushtotalk.py scripts. This flag works perfectly fine for those scripts, but is not available for the hotword.py script.

Anyone was able to set a language other than English for the Google Assistant SDK with the hotword?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We published a new release that should address the language selection issue with the hotwording sample:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/google-assistant-sdk/0.4.1

Can you give it another try using the instructions in the bug report?
https://github.com/googlesamples/assistant-sdk-python/issues/146#issuecomment-354217352

Comment: hotword still does not contain language settings and it seem it uses some default setting from idk where